# How can a function communicate with a prototype in an embeddable javascript widget?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build an embeddable javascript widget. The following (example) is included in a script tag.

```
(function (window) {

    function TestFunction(params) {
        console.log("init");
        this.someVal = "ThisVal";
    }

    TestFunction.prototype.protoFunc = function () {
        return "Hello " + this.someVal;
    };

    function hello() {
        return eval("TestFunction.protoFunc();");
    }

}(window));
```

When I instantiate the widget as follows

```
let test = TestFunction({});
```

If I then type

```
test.protoFunc();
```

> Hello ThisVal

will be printed. However if the hello function fires it throws an error saying that `TestFunction.protoFunc is not a function`. Is there a way that the `hello()` function can fire the `TestFunction.prototype.protoFunc` function?

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the example a bit. The workflow is now object driven. If I misunderstood you please give me some more information.

```js
(function (window) {

  // Object instance
  let instance = null;

  // Class definition
  var TestFunction = function (params) {
      console.log("init");
      this.options = params;
      
      setTimeout(hello, 100); // triggering after initiation
  }

  // Class method
  TestFunction.prototype.protoFunc = function () {
      console.log("Hello " + this.options.name);
  };

  // the triggering function
  function hello() {
      return eval("instance.protoFunc()");
  }

  // initiate the instance
  instance = new TestFunction({ name: 'Jon Doe' });
  
  hello(); // trigger outside of class
}(window));
```

I've another example to show you how capsulating works.

```js
var TestFunction = (function() {
  function TestFunction(params) {
    console.log('init');
    this.options = params;
  }
  TestFunction.prototype.setName = function(name) {
    this.options.name = name;
  };
  TestFunction.prototype.getName = function() {
    return this.options.name;
  };
  TestFunction.prototype.protoFunc = function() {
    console.log("Hello " + this.getName());
  };
  return TestFunction;
}());

var test = new TestFunction({
  name: 'test'
});

test.protoFunc();
test.setName('Wuhu!');
test.protoFunc();
```

Comment: Hey Jason, thank you for responding. I've updated the question to be a little closer to the scenario at hand - trying to use eval... I'm not sure that the "static" function is workable. The widget takes different values in params when instantiated and these change as the widget is used on e.g. `this.someVal = "ThisVal";` can become `this.someVal = "covfefe";` outside the widget or from within the widget code.

Comment: @user714852 `this` is only accessiable within an object. otherwise you schould use it staticly. I've updated the first scenario a bit and made it all object based. Normaly you use setter or getter to communicate between class intern and extern. It means capsulating of data